# Relays in series connection?

Tags: relay

Can i connect 2 relays of the same specs and same coil voltage of 12 in series ie 86 of one relay to positive battery, it's 85 joined to 86 of the other relay and obviously the end 85 to ground??

Answer (score 2):

Both relays need 12V to reliably operate the coil, in series they will only get 6V.

So, no this is not a good idea.

The best is to connect them in parallel and they will operate at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I apply 6v to one relay by using voltage regulator. The relay works. Actually, I want voltage drop on each relays be about 6 vol and current 0.04 amps. Is there any extra diode I should connect in between the 2 relays so that reverse current will not flow???

Comment: Why try to operate a 12V relay with 6V? use 12V or get relays with 6V coils... you may end up with an unreliable performance...

Comment: Why would it only get 6V? What is reducing it by 1/2? The power going through is still 12V. What am I missing, Mike?

Comment: My goal is....I want those 2 relays to control one remote door lock module and one window closer module at the same time by cutting power supplies to each modules whenever any door is opened. The trouble is when only 1 relay is used, a significant 0.12 amps is drawn. Then, for all 4 doors, .012x4. So, by dropping to 6 volt each, I could easily obtained .04 amps with extra relay connected in series. Hope this is clear. Awaiting more suggestions.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  If you wire the 2 coils in series the voltage will be shared equally between the 2 coils, so each will only see 6 volts and since the total resistance is doubled, the current will be halved.  Wiring them in parallel will put 12v across both coils and they will get the full current they require to energize them.

Comment: @ThangTons You probably wont be able to 'reliably' turn the relays on with only 6v.  You can get relays with multiple contacts so just one relay will be able to switch multiple devices.

Comment: Please suggest a relay of 12 v coil voltage and coil current of max .04 amps.

Comment: @ThangTons Why 0.04 amps?  You need to give more information about what you are doing.  You could use a transistor to switch a larger current.

Comment: When one door is open, 0.04 amps max be drawn. If all 4 doors are opened, 0.04x4 amps is drawn. I want this current draw to be at the most .04 amps. Otherwise, if any doors are left open for instance 5 hrs straight, the battery will die. This current is disabling both the remote locking and auto windows close unit by cutting power supply to each units. Otherwise, the car would still be operable, ie car lock or autoclose windows, even if any door is open.

Comment: @ThangTons I think you calculations are off somewhat.  0.04A * 4 * 5hrs is only 0.8Ah.  Car batteries are around 100Ah. Even with a 50Ah battery, you would need to leave it on for 62 hours to flatten the battery.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact calculation. My car is i20 1.2 petrol with complete new 45 ah battery SF flash start with a circle transparent indicator on its upper surface ie red for maintenance check, green for charging is ok, and white for needs charging. Now, the indicator turns from green to almost complete white very quickly in just 30 hrs when only one relay is used which control both the said modules or units. This is my position why I want 2 relays to drop to 0.04 amps significantly thereby extending the signal color to white for more hrs say 80 hrs.

Comment: @Paulster2 Power is measured in Watts, not volts. Watts is the product of Amps * Volts. The two relay coils in series will act like a voltage divider ie two resistances in series, so the voltage measured in between the resistance or coils if you prefer will be 6V approximately as the coils may not have identical resistances.