# Transistor as a switch?

Tags: electrical

I want to use transistor or the like as a switch to close and open a ciruit whose voltage is 12 volt DC. Also, the transistor under same 12 v DC source must be operable at max 0.03 amps or 30 mAmps to open or close the said circuit. I want transistor current to be at most 0.03. Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Use one of the relays mentioned here : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/67996/10976

Comment: Use transistor spec sheets to find what you need, you may need to consider a more involved circuit...

Comment: This should be enlightening: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5336/i-dont-care-how-a-transistor-works-how-do-i-get-one-to-work

Answer (score 1):

A MOSFET is better as a switch and it needs no current (mA), only voltage. Search in YouTube for MOSFET switch and you will find what you need.